# Memory keeps on growing after writing large number of files

Tags: python, file, memory

I've a sample program shown below which open a file and writes a 100kb of string into the file and closes the file.

```
for a in xrange(100000):
    file_to = open('.//OutputFiles/Data' + str(a) + '.xml', "w")
    file_to.write(100kb_String)
    file_to.close()
```

The issue with this code is, the memory keeps on growing and doesn't release memory to OS. After the above code has run and if I remove the files from physical disk using rm the memory goes back to OS. gc.collect() is not working. I tried with subprocesses as below but still no luck.

```
def worker(a):
    file_to = open('.//OutputFiles/Data' + str(a) + '.xml', "w")
    file_to.write(100kb_string)
    file_to.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(100000):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Is there anyway to better handle this situation?

Comment: I tried to replicate and I don't see any growth in memory.  Maybe your system has a RAM disk or disk caching scheme that is holding onto memory when you write files.

Comment: Maybe you can try looking through the ideas in this article: http://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2013/08/03/diagnosing-memory-leaks-python.html There are a couple useful libraries in both Python stdlibs and pip that let you monitor Python's objects and memory usage. I'm not sure what the problem could be since you only seem to be cycling two variables, `a`, and `file_to`, and Python's GC collector should automatically clean up orphan objects.

Comment: @BradBudlong,   can I know what OS and python version you are running on? I am running on Amazon EC2 linux AMI with 2.7.9 python version.

Comment: @Pavan I ran with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu on a laptop

Comment: Precisely what did you observe that lead you to believe that the "memory keeps on growing"?

Comment: Yes. Here are more details. Before running the script memory shows 456 as follows using htop.

  Mem[||||                 456/15068MB]     Tasks: 34, 4 thr; 1 running

and here is after running the script it shows 826.

  Mem[|||||||||||||||||||||826/15068MB]     Tasks: 36, 4 thr; 1 running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it! It is basically not python's problem. As @Brad said it is cache problem. I followed what is mentioned in this page and the memory is back to OS.

http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html